# Coldfusion StructSetMetaData not updating items in an array inside a structure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a struct named requestStruct that looks like this:

> {"api_version":"1","SourceId":"99","CampaignId":"999","policy":{"zip":"60644","street_address":"43 Memory Lane","email":"test@test.com","currently_insured":"true","coverage_level":"2","current_carrier":"28","current_insured_duration":"7"},"drivers":[{"first_name":"Bat","last_name":"Man","birth_date":"1966-07-07","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"},{"first_name":"Boy","last_name":"Wonder","birth_date":"1966-07-07","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"},{"first_name":"Cat","last_name":"Woman","birth_date":"1966-06-06","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"},{"first_name":"Bat","last_name":"Girl","birth_date":"1966-01-01","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"}]}

This is JSON being sent to another company's API so I have no control over the structure or datatypes that they require. Every value needs to be string when it is converted to JSON but Coldfusion wants to convert a string like "99" to just the number 99 when using serializeJSON. So I am using StructSetMetaData to make sure they are converted into JSON as strings.

These statements work fine:

```
<cfscript>                   
    metadata = {
        api_version: {type:"string",name:"api_version"},
        SourceId: {type:"string",name:"SourceId"},
        CampaignId: {type:"string",name:"CampaignId"}
    };
    StructSetMetaData(requestStruct,metadata);
</cfscript>

<cfscript>
    metadata = {
        policy:{
            keys:{
                "zip":{type:"string",name:"zip"},
                "email":{type:"string",name:"email"},
                "currently_insured":{type:"string",name:"currently_insured"},
                "coverage_level":{type:"string",name:"coverage_level"},
                "current_carrier":{type:"string",name:"current_carrier"},
                "current_insured_duration":{type:"string",name:"current_insured_duration"}
            }
        }
    };
    StructSetMetaData(requestStruct,metadata);
 </cfscript>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do the same to the drivers part of the struct as it contains an array.

I tried this and it had no effect:

```
<cfscript>
    metadata = {
        drivers:{
            keys:{
                "homeowner":{type:"string",name:"homeowner"},
                "sr22":{type:"string",name:"sr22"}
            }
        }
    };
    StructSetMetaData(requestStruct,metadata);
</cfscript>
```

I tried this and it had no effect:

```
<cfscript>
    metadata = {
        drivers:{
            keys:{
                "homeowner[0]":{type:"string",name:"homeowner"},
                "sr22[0]":{type:"string",name:"sr22"}
            }
        }
    };
    StructSetMetaData(requestStruct,metadata);
</cfscript>
```

How can I set the metadata for the keys in the array of structs in the driver key?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running?

Comment: We're on version 2016.0.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this. For array inside structure you need to provide the metadata in the same way meta data is provided for [arraySetMetaData](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraysetmetadata.html) function.

```
<cfset requestStruct = {"api_version":"1","SourceId":"99","CampaignId":"999","policy":{"zip":"60644","street_address":"43 Memory Lane","email":"test@test.com","currently_insured":"true","coverage_level":"2","current_carrier":"28","current_insured_duration":"7"},"drivers":[{"first_name":"Bat","last_name":"Man","birth_date":"1966-07-07","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"},{"first_name":"Boy","last_name":"Wonder","birth_date":"1966-07-07","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"},{"first_name":"Cat","last_name":"Woman","birth_date":"1966-06-06","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"},{"first_name":"Bat","last_name":"Girl","birth_date":"1966-01-01","homeowner":"true","sr22":"false"}]}>
<cfscript>
    metadata = {
      api_version: {type:"string",name:"api_version"},
      SourceId: {type:"string",name:"SourceId"},
      CampaignId: {type:"string",name:"CampaignId"},
      policy:{
          keys:{
              "zip":{type:"string",name:"zip"},
              "email":{type:"string",name:"email"},
              "currently_insured":{type:"string",name:"currently_insured"},
              "coverage_level":{type:"string",name:"coverage_level"},
              "current_carrier":{type:"string",name:"current_carrier"},
              "current_insured_duration":{type:"string",name:"current_insured_duration"}
          }
      }
    };
    driversMetadata = { 
      items: []
    };
    for(driver in requestStruct.drivers){
      driversMetadata.items.append({
        "homeowner":{type:"string", name:"homeowner"},
        "sr22":{type:"string", name:"sr22"}
      });
    }
    metadata.drivers = driversMetadata;
    StructSetMetaData(requestStruct, metadata);
</cfscript>
```

**[DEMO](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=9b4b1e82-7ca5-4bbd-97f8-4b966a474e7d/1b723f6e-4749-49aa-be73-bf197c4a32a5/808f6b1b-9f5f-47f1-a2d3-6a54962cdb10.cfm)**